# Why must superpartners have the same gauge quantum numbers?

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry

The title leaves it quite clear, why must superpartners have the same gauge quantum numbers?

Comment: How would you be able to add the thing SUSY produces to its superpartner if they transformed in different representations (and hence lay in different vector spaces)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind not sure what you are getting at. not all symmetries have to commute with SUSY (those that don't are called R-symmetries)

Comment: gauge symmetries commute with SUSY. not sure whether there is any deeper answer than that

Comment: @innisfree: While your answer is correct I think it needs to be expanded on to be clear to someone without experience with supersymmetry...

Comment: @JeffDror sure, yes, it needs to be expanded. tbh, i don't know much about gauging R-symmetries - i think it's problematic

Answer (score 2):

A bosonic symmetry that acts differently on the different components of a supermultiplet is an R-symmetry. Such a symmetry does not commute with the supercharges. Since the commutator between an R-symmetry and a supercharge gives something Grassmann odd, it has to given another supercharge. Schematically
$$
[R,Q] = Q
$$
or in terms of variations acting on some field
$$
[ \delta_R , \delta_Q ] = \delta_Q
$$
If we gauge an R-symmetry then the variation $\delta_R$ is allowed to depend on the coordinates $x$. But then from the algebra above so is $\delta_Q$
$$
[ \delta_R(x) , \delta_Q(x) ] = \delta_Q(x)
$$
So gauging an R-symmetry leads to *local supersymmetry*. To see where this takes us we can consider the supersymmetry algebra
$$
\{ Q , Q \} = P
$$
or
$$
\{ \delta_Q , \delta_Q \} = \delta_P
$$
where $\delta_P$ is a translation. If $\delta_Q$ depends on $x$ we get
$$
\{ \delta_Q(x) , \delta_Q(x) \} = \delta_P(x)
$$
so local supersymmetry automatically leads to invariance under *local translations* or in other words under *diffeomorphisms*. Hence, the only way to gauge an R-symmetry is in supergravity. In particular in a [gauged supergravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauged_supergravity) the gravitino is charged with respect to some gauge field while the graviton is not, so this gives an example where superpartners don't carry the same gauge quantum numbers.

Comment: How well motivated is it that that SM gauge group is chosen to commute with SUSY? Could I make the SM gauge groups an R-symmetry?

Comment: @innisfree: to make the $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ gauge group of the standard model a gauged R-symmetry you would (obviously) need an R-symmetry group that contains this as a subalgebra. Unfortunately I don't think even the $SO(8)$ R-symmetry of maximally supersymmetric $\mathcal{N}=8$ sugra in 4d is enough to fit this (in normal unified theories need an $SU(5)$ or $SO(10)$)

Comment: does the R-symmetry group have to be simple or semi-simple? am i free to pick the R-symmetry group? why can't I pick $G_{SM}$ and build a theory?

Comment: no, the supersymmetry algebra strongly restricts what R-symmetry is possible, at least as long as you don't want to break Lorentz invariance. In 4d you can organise the supercharges into eg Weyl spinors and the R-symmetry has to rotate among themselves. If you have $\mathcal{N}$ supercharges the 4d R-symmetry will in general be someting like $SU(\mathcal{N})$ or $SO(\mathcal{N})$ depending on what reality conditions you can impose.